# Extending lib.d.ts interfaces?

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I have some code that handles a drop event and checks if I have to deal with dropped files:

```
public handleDrop(evt: DropEvent): boolean {
  var isUpload: boolean; = false;
  var dt: DataTransfer = evt.DataTransfer;

  dt.types.forEach((type)=>{
    // dt.types is of type DOMStringList
    if(type === "File"){
      isUpload = true;
    }
  })
  return isUpload;
}
```

It works just as it is supposed to be, but the TS-compiler gives me following error message:

```
(117,16): error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'DOMStringList'.
```

First of all, DataTransfer.types will always be an array, so in my understanding I should have access to its array methods.

I tried to create a workaround for my problem, by merging a custom `DOMStringList Interface` to the one defined in my `lib.d.ts`:

```
declare interface DOMStringList {
  forEach(cb: Function): any;
}
```

IntelliJ recognizes the interface and does not show me an error for `dt.types.forEach` anymore.

However my ts-compiler still throws an error and does not seem to recognize my merged interface.

What is the proper way to tell my ts-compiler that I should be able to use array functions on an `DOMStringList`?
The problem occurs for other generic types like `FileList` as well.

EDIT:
`ts.config.ts`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "app/typings/app.typings.ts",
    "typings/tsd.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please also include your `tsconfig.json` or command line compiler arguments that you use.

Comment: @zlumer thanks. I appended it